# CUP file for MIPS Assembler

Tags: java, assembly, mips

I try to create a MIPS Assembler (simulator) using the JFlex and JCUP libraries. I created the .flex source file and generated the Lexer.java file, but I'm not sure how to create the .cup source file. I'm not sure how to define all those 'terminals' and 'non terminals', the precedence, the grammar, etc.

Does anyone have any example of such a file?

Thank you!